# Error: 'Cannot call value of non-function type' on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

The second and third lines of the following code were working on swift 2.3 and since I updated to swift 3, I've been getting the error  *Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'* for both of them:

```
let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary                    

let lat = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lat") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double
let lon = ((((dic["results"] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "geometry") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "location") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "lng") as AnyObject).object(0) as! Double

self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(lon, andLatitude: lat, andTitle: self.searchResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
```

This is the callback from a google maps search.

The JSON that the method is reading is this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "São Paulo",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "São Paulo",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "State of São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "SP",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brazil",
               "short_name" : "BR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "São Paulo, State of São Paulo, Brazil",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -23.3566039,
                  "lng" : -46.36508449999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -24.0082209,
                  "lng" : -46.825514
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -23.5505199,
               "lng" : -46.63330939999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -23.3566039,
                  "lng" : -46.36508449999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -24.0082209,
                  "lng" : -46.825514
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJ0WGkg4FEzpQRrlsz_whLqZs",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Does anyone knows what I have do change to make it work?

Comment: That code is horrible anyway. Unpack it to several lines and it will be much more readable. The majority of the lines is repeated, so it is no big deal to separate the statements

Comment: I do not understand `object(0)` in your code, and your code, even if un-converted to Swift 2, is full of bad practices... Can you show us an example string representation of your JSON data?

Comment: The code may be hard to read, but if it worked in Swift 2.3 and not 3, there must be a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things which are pretty bad in Swift when parsing JSON:

- casting to `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, which have no type information.
- casting to `AnyObject` which is very unspecified.
- `valueForKey` which is a key-value coding method and not necessary in this case.
- The option `mutableleaves` which is meaningless when using Swift types and never needed when the objects are only read.

Sue all tutorials which suggest that poorly programming habit. ;-)

Consider that `AnyObject` has been replaced with `Any` in Swift 3.

JSON supports only two collection types, `array` – represented by `[]` – and `dictionary` – represented by `{}`.

To parse JSON reliably you have to read the JSON carefully to identify the structure and tell the compiler the types of the nodes.

Your main mistake is the wrong type of the value for key `results` which is an **array**.

This code checks for the existence of all keys with optional bindings and also if the array is not empty and the dictionary for `location` contains 2 items:

```
if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any],
  let results = jsonObject["results"] as? [[String:Any]], !results.isEmpty,
  let geometry = results[0]["geometry"] as? [String:Any],
  let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:Double],
  let lat = location["lat"], let lng = location["lng"] {

  print("lat: \(lat) - lng: \(lng)")
}
```

Apple has published a comprehensive article [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Comment: Why don't you include `lat` and `lng` into Optional bindings? It may be safer than just checking `count`.

Comment: @OOP If `location` is not empty, what else as `lat` and `lng` could it contain?

Comment: Then, if the server is working well and returning a valid JSON, all other type checking is not needed?

Comment: No, all keys including `location` could be missing, but I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, for including my opinion and showing the link to the nice article.